# "That's what is" and "that's what that's"

Tags: grammaticality

To the best of my knowledge, we can say "That's what is called camouflage."

If I'm not wrong, here *what* means "the thing which." So, the sentence makes sense. But I just need a native English speaker to verify that the following sentence is also correct.

> That's what **that**'s called‌**:** camouflage.

Please notice that in the latter sentence there is a colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That "trick" of using a colon before *camouflage* is misleading. Generally speaking, in written forms, ***that*** refers to *something previously mentioned*. For example...

> "The zebra has stripes for *camouflage*. That's what that is called."

In my example, the first ***that*** simply functions as a "pronoun", standing in for the word *camouflage*.

The word ***what*** also effectively functions as a pronoun (it just refers back to the first *that*).

The second ***that*** isn't quite so simple, in that you can't say it represents one or more preceding words. Loosely speaking, it stands in for *the fact that (or, reason why) the zebra has stripes*.

The actual punctuation in OP's sentence is a matter of style. Valid alternatives include a comma, period, or dash (they all just represent a "break/pause" in speech). The important thing is that either *[whatever is being identified as camouflage]* should already have been mentioned in the discourse, or the speaker should be *pointing at it as he speaks*

---

It's *sometimes* okay to use ***that*** as a "forward reference" for something you haven't yet identified by anything you said or wrote earlier, but this would normally require a very strong implication that the speaker (and probably his audience, too) are at least *thinking about* whatever ***that*** refers to, even if they haven't specifically mentioned it.

---

Assuming that OP is concerned about whether he can validly use ***that*** twice in the same utterance, the answer is "Yes". In this specific example, they refer to two closely-related referents (a word, and the thing represented by that word). But the referents can be completely different...

> "Where's the zebra? It's hidden in the grass. That's where that is"
>    (first ***that*** = hidden in the grass, second ***that*** = the zebra).

...or they can both refer to exactly the same thing...

> "What's hiding in the grass? It's a zebra. That's what that is"
>    (both ***that***'s = the zebra).

Comment: Good point. In fact, I presumed that the O.P.'s sentence was the concluding sentence of a longer paragraph, in which case, the sentence would be fine as written.

Comment: @J.R.: There's not a lot of context here, so I'm not really sure exactly what OP is asking about. But I'm guessing he wonders if it's okay to use ***that*** twice in the same sentence. Which it *is*, and I hope I've shown how it works when the two ***that***'s represent (slightly) different things (one the real-world referent, the other the *word* for that referent).

Comment: Yep, that's what that's about: _dual that's_. ;^)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you so much for your detailed answer.

Comment: @J.R. What I've asked here is the whole context I have. Indeed I've heard or read a similar sentence with similar structure, but I can't remember when or where. It had the part "That's what that's", and I added the rest ("called‌: camouflage") using my own imagination.

Comment: @Nate: If you look at some written instances of [That's what that's called](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22That's+what+that's+called%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), I think you'll see that they're mostly structured as per my first example (i.e. - the first ***that*** refers back to the last *word* of the preceding utterance, and the second refers to *the actual thing* represented by that word). But there are far more hits for the more "natural" [That's what **it's** called](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22That's+what+it's+called%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Answer (score 0):

In the first sentence, *what* is a relative pronoun meaning "the thing or the things that"; in the second sentence, *what* is a determiner.

The sentence is fine, but I would use *this* at the beginning.

> This is what that is called‌: camouflage.

Comment: If you're going to use "this", you might as well say, _This is called_ **camouflage**.

Comment: @J.R.: It would be just the same with *that*. OP might just as well have said *"**That** is called camouflage."*

Comment: @J.R. In the sentence I wrote _this_ is referring to _camouflage_, not the thing that is called _camouflage_. Indeed, the OP could simply say "that is called _camouflage_" and the sentence would be correct.

Comment: For some reason, I have no problem with the O.P.'s suggested sentence, but the longer version seems unnecessarily wordy to me. But that's just how it strikes me; all the of the suggestions here are indeed grammatical.